# Python to MySQL Database: What exception handling

Tags: python, mysql, database, exception

for a project at uni i need to insert different kinds of variables into a MySql Database. Connecting and Inserting the data so far works fine. I don't know how to handle potential errors though. Which potential mistakes and exceptions do i need to catch and take care of ?

In my code i used a main method to just test the program. In the final version just the connection and the SQL queries are copied into the main script. I am open to use either the MySQL or the mysql.connector. Also: Do i need to put the query into a try block aswell ? Here is my code so far:

```
import mysql.connector
import time
from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
    con = mysql.connector.connect(
        user= 'root',
        password= '',
        host='localhost',
        database= 'testdb')
    print("Connected.")
    cursor = con.cursor()
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    if e.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Passwort // Username")
    elif e.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("DataBase does not exist")
    else:
        print(e)


def insert_temp(Temperatur_ID, Zeitpunkt, Wert, Thermometer_ID):
    query = "INSERT INTO Temperatur (Temperatur_ID, Zeitpunkt, Wert,  Thermometer_ID)" \
            "VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)"
    args= (Temperatur_ID, Zeitpunkt, Wert, Thermometer_ID)
    cursor.execute(query, args)
    con.commit()


def main():
    # just test values so far
    value = 18.5;
    insert_temp(' ', time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), value, '1');
    cursor.close()
    con.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

please note that i have very little experience in python programming

Comment: try except block is not mandatory... a specially at this level of abstraction. Think about complicated program, where DB is one of many levels of communication. Then catching exception and reacting on it is crucial - in other case you can spent days tracking why it fails...

Comment: so there is no error handling at all needed ? The script we will use is gonna run the whole time and will insert the different temperatures plus the timestamps every 10 minutes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is working code and as such should be on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Python code needs to be indented correctly.  The best way post your code is to paste it into the Stack Overflow editor, highlight the entire code, and press Ctrl-K.

Comment: @RememberMyFart - I've updated formatting. According to your question. You don't have to track exceptions at all. In Java there are checked exceptions, so you have to - if not - your code would not compile. However if you wish to react somehow if exception occurred? Maybe sleep - reconnect - retry? Maybe report problem somewhere? That are "issues" addressed by exception handling...